# "dd/mm/yyyy" date format in excel through vba

Tags: date, excel, vba

I am trying to write a date in "dd/mm/yyyy" format in excel sheet thru excel-vba. I achieved it using `Cells(1, 1).Value = Format(StartDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")`. and my cell value comes out to be `30/04/2014`, which is good.....

But there is some weird problem... 
Since I have to iterate the startDate for whole month by everytime adding it by 1, so the next value comes out to be `1/5/2014` instead of `01/05/2014` until 12th of each month `12/5/2014` and from 13th, the month is again changing to two digits `13/05/2014`....

I want it all in two digits as I have to again search for these dates using Range.Find method, in which I am passing value with "dd/mm/yyyy" fromat.

Comment: while debugging, I am getting the values with two digits `01/05/2014`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got it

> Cells(1, 1).Value = StartDate
>   
> Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

Basically, I need to set the cell format, instead of setting the date.

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is with attempting to change your month by adding 1. 1 in date serials in Excel is equal to 1 day. Try changing your month by using the following:

```
NewDate = Format(DateAdd("m",1,StartDate),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: I have to add days, not the months... I an getting the required result while debugging, but when its inserting in the excel, the format is not considering 2 digits in date and month column

Comment: What type of object is `StartDate`? Can you try: `Format(StartDate+1,"dd/mm/yyyy")` and see if you get the format you want?

Comment: You may also be able to use the `.NumberFormat` property of the range.  For example, if your date you want formatted as dd/mm/yyyy is in cell A1 you could use `Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"`.  I'm not sure how (or why) this differs from `Format` though, just a suggestion that might help.