# Excel VBA code to split cells and copy date to new column, some date values changing

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have the following section of code that is splitting a value in a cell based on the keyword "Milestone", then creating a new column on a new sheet and pasting the date to it.

```
Sheets("DemandTable").Rows("1").Copy Sheets("DataSheet").Range("A1")

With Sheets("DemandTable")

LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

pasteRowIndex = 2

For r = LastRow To 1 Step -1
 If IsError(.Cells(r, "L").Value) Then
     .Cells(r, "L").EntireRow.Delete

ElseIf LCase(.Cells(r, "L").Value) Like LCase("Milestone*") Then
  If UBound(Split(.Cells(r, "L"), ",")) > 0 Then
      i = i + 1
      ReDim v(1 To i)
      v(i) = pasteRowIndex
      End If

  Sheets("DemandTable").Rows(r).Copy Sheets("DataSheet").Rows(pasteRowIndex)
 pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1
End If
Next r
End With

With Sheets("DataSheet")

newLastRow = pasteRowIndex

If IsArray(v) Then
    .Columns(13).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
     For i = 1 To newLastRow
       If InStr(1, .Cells(i, "L"), ",") Then
        .Cells(i, "M").Value = Split(.Cells(i, "L"), ",")(1)
        End If
    Next i
End If
```

The issue I have is that the values after the "Milestone" keyword are dates, and when they are copied to the new column they on some occasions change value e.g. 01/10/2017 can become 10/01/2017.

Is there a way I can format the new dates so that they don't change values and are shown as dd/mm/yyyy? Anything I try in terms of formatting, does not correct the swapping of the day and month digits? Please note this only happens for some rows.

Thanks

Comment: What do you have your regional settings set to?

Answer (score 0):

This question is duplicated and already answered.

> ["dd/mm/yyyy" date format in excel through vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144096/dd-mm-yyyy-date-format-in-excel-through-vba)

Solution:

```
Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Comment: Then mark it as a duplicate and not link to it in an answer